# Applications of generating functions to number theory

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, generating-functions, analytic-number-theory

I am familiar (at least at a cursory level) with the extensive role generating functions play in the theory of partitions. What are some other prominent applications of generating functions to number theory?

Comment: The [Hardy-Littlewood circle method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_circle_method).

Answer (score 3):

This answer is by no means exhaustive, it's presumably hardly more than a startup for your question.

Considering the *theory of partitions* as part of *additive number theory* which uses quite often analytical methods, we can say that generating functions are a *ubiquitous* tool in analytic number theory and not only within the theory of partitions. To underpin this statement I like to quote from D.J.Newman's *Analytic Number Theory*.

> From D.J.Newman's Analytic Number Theory, chapter I: *The Idea of Analytic Number Theory*
>
> The most intriguing thing about Analytic Number Theory (the use of *Analysis*, or *function theory*, in number theory) is its very existence! How could one use properties of continuous valued functions to determine properties of those most discrete items, the integers. Analytic functions? What has differentiability got to do with counting? The astonishment mounts further when we learn that complex zeros of a certain analytic function are *the* basic tools in the investigation of the primes.
> The answer to all this bewilderment is given by the two words *generating functions*.

The following chapter II deals with partition functions, but then follow (besides other ones) chapters about the *Waring Problem*, about *$L$-Series* and the *prime number theorem*.

In *multiplicative number theory* generating functions take the form of *Dirichlet Series* to answer questions using *sieve methods*, questions about *arithmetic functions* or the *distribution of primes* to name just a few areas.

In my job I've sometimes to do with generating functions in *cryptography* which could together with the usage of generating functions in *computational number theory* also be seen as part of number theory.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This was not part of the OP's question, but do you have any suggestions for a introductory textbook, course notes, etc on multiplicative number theory that relates to generating functions?

Comment: @Gamma Function: A fine, easily accessible text for me was *Introduction to Arithmetical Functions* from P.J.McCarthy. The seven chapters of the book: Multiplicative Functions, Ramanujan Sums, Counting Solutions of Congrences, Dirichlet Series and Generating Functions, Asymptotic Properties of Arithmetical Functions and Generalized Arithmetical Functions. You may also want to look at section 2.6 of H.Wilfs [Generatingfunctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfologyLinked2.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

One can view $q$-expansions of modular forms as a kind of generating function. They contain information on many number theoretic objects such as partitions, divisor sums, point counts on elliptic curves, representation numbers of quadratic forms, class numbers etc.

Comment: Do you have textbooks in mind that would be well suited for an advanced undergraduate?

Comment: There is a gentle book by Kilford ("Modular forms: A classical and computational introduction") and there are other good books by William Stein ("Modular forms: A computational approach") and Zagier ("1-2-3 of modular forms") etc. However you can find a lot of good materials online. When you first learn about modular forms it is tough to see the forest for the trees, the definition is seemingly unrelated to anything number theoretical. Most books are incredibly secretive on their uses and appear to study more the details in proofs etc. It takes quite a while to get to the "juicy stuff".

Comment: However it is all there, just takes a while to pick it up! But the more you study them the more number theory you find. One of the first basic results that proved to me the power of modular forms is their use in finding non-trivial relationships between power divisor sums. Something incredibly non-trivial like $\sigma_7(n) = \sigma_3(n) + 120\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sigma_3(k)\sigma_3(n-k)$ really boils down to two generating series having to be equal considered as modular forms of weight $8$ (a vector space of dimension $1$).